# How to change Rows and Columns in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

[image: Screenshot of my Power Query Editor]

Here is a screenshot of my data in the Power Query Editor. I am new to this program so please bear with me.

I added a bunch of json files from Azure Blob Storage as a data source and then I pressed "combine files". This is the result. My goal is to create a line chart that shows power over time. As you can see, I the leftmost column shows the name of the file, while the middle column shows the name of the variables saved in the file and the rightmost one has the values.

I want to have the "date" values on the X-axis and the "power_mw" values on the Y-axis of my line chart. I assume for that I have to create a column with the date values and another column with the power values, but this is what I get when I press "combine files" and I don't know how to edit it. Can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pivoting the `Name` column using the `Value` column unaggregated.

[image: Pivot Column Dialog]

You can find the pivoting commands under the Transform tab in the query editor.

After pivoting, you should have this:

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi and thank you. If i right-click on the Name column,  I can only press on "unpivot selected columns". I am not sure what you mean by "using Value as your values column"

Comment: Thanks so much! One question, last week everything worked. For some reason now  Ikeep getting this message after I try to pivot  `Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.
Details:
    List` . Do you know why? I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: This will happen if you have multiple date rows with the same name. In this situation, Don't Aggregate doesn't know how to pick between them. If you want to keep both, try adding an index column before pivoting so the rows stay unique.